# PHP : Google plus Oauth 2.0 - Getting Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Working on *Sign in with Google*, using *PHP Lib v2, Oauth 2.0*.

After long time spending on it finally I configured, it worked once fine but after that it is not working. On the clicking of sign in link, it will take user for authentication to Google. Working fine till then authentication done.

At the time of callback with `GET` variables:

```
?code=something&authuser=0&prompt=consent&session_state=something
```

It is generating following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message
>   'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php:115
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php(127):
>   Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, 4/xUGSPbXR0LNzW...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client\index.php(40):
>   Google_Client->authenticate('4/xUGSPbXR0LNzW...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php
>   on line 115

Using following code (it will help you to understand):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  $url = filter_var($me['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $img = filter_var($me['image']['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $name = filter_var($me['displayName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  $personMarkup = "<a rel='me' href='$url'>$name</a><div><img src='$img'></div>";

  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);
  $activityMarkup = '';
  foreach($activities['items'] as $activity) {
    $url = filter_var($activity['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    $title = filter_var($activity['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $content = filter_var($activity['object']['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $activityMarkup .= "<div class='activity'><a href='$url'>$title</a><div>$content</div></div>";
  }

  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
<body>
<header><h1>Google+ Sample App</h1></header>
<div class="box">

<?php if(isset($personMarkup)): ?>
<div class="me"><?php print $personMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if(isset($activityMarkup)): ?>
<div class="activities">Your Activities: <?php print $activityMarkup ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
  if(isset($authUrl)) {
    print "<a class='login' id='g_pop' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
      print_r($me);
   print "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
  }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Get source files from here: <s>[Google APIs Client Library for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list)</s>

Already done:

- Client ID:   OK
- Client secret: OK
- Redirect URIs: OK
- Google+ API: ON

**Note:**

Working on localhost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had same issue. Fixed it by deleting the extra space from the client secret. When you copy it from google api console you get an extra space.

Comment: Yes , extra space or anything in client secret will give you this error, removing that solved my issue....thanks

Answer (score 3):

Double check that your google app credentials (client id, client secret, API key) are valid and passed to client correctly.